# Cannot login on Zabbix docker installation

Tags: docker, zabbix

I am trying to bring a 3 layer (frontend,server and db) initial instalation of zabbix 3.x but I cannot pass the login page.

Here are my docker lines:

http://pastebin.com/79g1Mucb

And here are my docker logs:

- DB:

"The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

```
pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
```

waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-01-11 09:25:23 BRST
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
 done
server started
CREATE DATABASE

CREATE ROLE

/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

LOG:  received fast shutdown request
LOG:  aborting any active transactions
waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-01-11 09:25:27 BRST
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  received smart shutdown request
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  database system is shut down
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-01-11 09:26:52 BRST
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started"

- SERVER:

"** Preparing the system
** Preparing Zabbix server

---

- DB_SERVER_HOST: zabbix-db
- DB_SERVER_PORT: 5432
- DB_SERVER_DBNAME: zabbix
- DB_SERVER_ZBX_USER: zabbix
- DB_SERVER_ZBX_PASS: a4d29cf3faab2ec897f2d11e599fe234

  ---

** Database 'zabbix' already exists. Please be careful with database owner!
** Creating 'zabbix' schema in PostgreSQL
** Fill the schema with initial data
** Preparing Zabbix server configuration file
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "ListenPort": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "SourceIP": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "LogType": 'console'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "LogFile": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "LogFileSize": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "PidFile": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "DebugLevel": '3'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "DBHost": 'zabbix-db'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "DBName": 'zabbix'... updated
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "DBUser": 'zabbix'... updated
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "DBPort": '5432'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "DBPassword": 'a4d29cf3faab2ec897f2d11e599fe234'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartPollers": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartIPMIPollers": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartPollersUnreachable": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartTrappers": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartPingers": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartDiscoverers": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartHTTPPollers": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartTimers": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartEscalators": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "JavaGateway": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "JavaGatewayPort": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartJavaPollers": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartVMwareCollectors": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "VMwareFrequency": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "VMwarePerfFrequency": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "VMwareCacheSize": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "VMwareTimeout": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "SNMPTrapperFile": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartSNMPTrapper": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "HousekeepingFrequency": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "MaxHousekeeperDelete": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "SenderFrequency": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "CacheSize": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "CacheUpdateFrequency": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartDBSyncers": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "HistoryCacheSize": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "HistoryIndexCacheSize": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "TrendCacheSize": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "ValueCacheSize": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "Timeout": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "TrapperTimeout": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "UnreachablePeriod": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "UnavailableDelay": ''... removed
:Unlinking stale socket /var/run/supervisor.sock
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "UnreachableDelay": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "AlertScriptsPath": '/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "ExternalScripts": '/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "FpingLocation": '/usr/sbin/fping'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "Fping6Location": '/usr/sbin/fping6'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "SSHKeyLocation": '/var/lib/zabbix/ssh_keys'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "LogSlowQueries": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "StartProxyPollers": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "ProxyConfigFrequency": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "ProxyDataFrequency": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "SSLCertLocation": '/var/lib/zabbix/ssl/certs/'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "SSLKeyLocation": '/var/lib/zabbix/ssl/keys/'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "SSLCALocation": '/var/lib/zabbix/ssl/ssl_ca/'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "LoadModulePath": '/var/lib/zabbix/modules/'... added
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "TLSCAFile": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "TLSCRLFile": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "TLSCertFile": ''... removed
** Updating '/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf' parameter "TLSKeyFile": ''... removed
** Cleaning the system"

- FRONTEND:

"** Deploying Zabbix frontend (nginx) with postgresql database
** Preparing the system
** Preparing Zabbix web-interface

---

- DB_SERVER_HOST: zabbix-db
- DB_SERVER_PORT: 5432
- DB_SERVER_DBNAME: zabbix
- DB_SERVER_ZBX_USER: zabbix
- DB_SERVER_ZBX_PASS: a4d29cf3faab2ec897f2d11e599fe234

  ---

** Disable default vhosts
** Adding Zabbix virtual host (HTTP)
:2017/01/11 11:28:53 [alert] 33#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 256000) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2017/01/11 11:28:53 [alert] 34#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 256000) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2017/01/11 11:28:53 [alert] 36#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 256000) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2017/01/11 11:28:53 [alert] 37#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 256000) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2017/01/11 11:28:53 [alert] 35#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 256000) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
[11-Jan-2017 11:28:53] WARNING: Nothing matches the include pattern '/etc/php5/fpm.d/*.conf' from /etc/php5/php-fpm.conf at line 15.
**** Impossible to enable SSL support for Nginx. Certificates are missed.
** Preparing Zabbix frontend configuration file
** Updating '/etc/php5/conf.d/99-zabbix.ini' parameter "max_execution_time": '300'... updated
** Updating '/etc/php5/conf.d/99-zabbix.ini' parameter "memory_limit": '512M'... updated
** Updating '/etc/php5/conf.d/99-zabbix.ini' parameter "post_max_size": '64MB'... updated
** Updating '/etc/php5/conf.d/99-zabbix.ini' parameter "upload_max_filesize": '2M'... updated
** Updating '/etc/php5/conf.d/99-zabbix.ini' parameter "max_input_time": '300'... updated
** Updating '/etc/php5/conf.d/99-zabbix.ini' parameter "date.timezone": 'UTC'... updated
** Cleaning the system

#

** Executing supervisord
2017-01-11 11:28:51,808 CRIT Set uid to user 0
2017-01-11 11:28:51,808 CRIT Set uid to user 0
2017-01-11 11:28:51,808 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord_zabbix.conf" during parsing
2017-01-11 11:28:51,808 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord_zabbix.conf" during parsing
2017-01-11 11:28:51,827 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-01-11 11:28:51,827 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2017-01-11 11:28:51,827 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2017-01-11 11:28:51,827 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2017-01-11 11:28:52,836 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 31
2017-01-11 11:28:52,836 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 31
2017-01-11 11:28:52,842 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 32
2017-01-11 11:28:52,842 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 32
2017-01-11 11:28:54,338 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-01-11 11:28:54,338 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-01-11 11:28:54,338 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2017-01-11 11:28:54,338 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
10.0.2.2 - - [11/Jan/2017:11:30:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1218 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0" "-"
10.0.2.2 - - [11/Jan/2017:11:30:12 +0000] "GET /styles/blue-theme.css HTTP/1.1" 200 17854 "http://127.0.0.1:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0" "-"
..."

Now when I try to login with the default credentials Admin/zabbix the login page keeps redirecting me to itself.

Comment: This looks like a SELINUX issue. Do you have it enabled?

Comment: @dirmir, I actually figured out the problem. The isse was the extra B in --env="ZBX_POSTMAXSIZE=64MB". It should be --env="ZBX_POSTMAXSIZE=64M"

Answer (score 0):

The isse was the extra B in --env="ZBX_POSTMAXSIZE=64MB". It should be --env="ZBX_POSTMAXSIZE=64M"